# tar files only, no directories

Tags: tar

I can probably write a shell script to find files only, then pass the list to tar, but I am wondering whether there already is a built-in feature in tar that allows doing just that, in a single command line?

For example, I found the `--no-recursion` switch, but when I do:

```
tar --no-recursion -cvf mydir.tar mydir
```

It only archives the names of the entries in the directory (including subdirectories!), but it doesn't archive any files.

I also tried:

```
 tar --no-recursion -cvf mydir.tar mydir/*
```

But while it archives files only, it also archives the **names** of the subdirectories.

Is there a way to tell tar files only, no directories?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to create an archive with  "flat" structure (i.e. all files mixed up in one directory)?

Comment: You could create a new directory and `find mydir -type f |xargs cp -t tempdir` and then tar tempdir.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz Yes, flat, but only from that directory, not from subdirectories.

Comment: @Kevin 1. Your method archives files in subdirectories, too. 2. Your command is actually the script that I am trying to avoid. :)

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're trying to do.  How about `find mydir -depth 1 -type f | xargs tar cf mydir.tar`

Comment: @Kevin GMTA. I was just testing the maxdepth feature of find in exactly the same syntax you posted, and it almost works: Filenames with spaces are not handled well. Surely there is a way to solve this.

Comment: sorry, that needs to be `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Ah, spaces.  Use find's -exec instead: `find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar cvf mydir.tar {} +`.  The `+` puts all the files on the same command line like xargs.

Comment: @Kevin, I just tested something that works:  `find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf mydir.tar`. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: @Kevin, and I just tested your `+` version as well and it also works, producing the same exact results. Please post it as answer so that I can accept. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As camh points out, the previous command had a small problem in that given too many file names, it would execute more than once, with later invocations silently wiping out the previous runs. Since we're not compressing too, we can append instead of overwrite:

```
find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar Avf mydir.tar
find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar Avf mydir.tar {} +
```

[Iocnarz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33781/11750) of using `tar`'s `--null` and `-T` options works as well.  If you have `cpio` installed, [camh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35917/11750) using it is also fine. And if you have `zsh` and don't mind using it for a command, [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24916/11750)  using a zsh glob (`*(.)`) seems the most straightforward.

---

The key was the `-maxdepth` option.
Final answer, dealing with spaces appropriately:

```
find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf mydir.tar
```

This should also work:

```
find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec tar cvf mydir.tar {} +
```

Comment: Both of these can result in multiple invocations of `tar`. Both `xargs` and `find` with the `+` variant has a maximum number of arguments that can be passed to tar. This will result in the second invocation of tar overwriting the output of the first.

Comment: Expanding on the xargs limit, xargs default to a maximum 128KiB command line. If the file list is larger, you get a second (or more) invocation of the command (tar), leading to silent data loss. You can use `-x` to force xargs to fail instead of losing data, and while better than a silent data loss bug, it's still not ideal. This sort bug is so dangerous because everything seems OK at first, but as the file list grows over time, you start triggering it and may not notice until you try to restore your backup. Then it's too late.

Comment: @camh You're right, thanks for pointing that out; I've updated to reflect that.

Comment: The "final answer" is not correct, if you use "tar c" without -T you might get partial results.

Answer (score 17):

When you want to use `find` with `tar`, the best way is to use `cpio` instead of `tar`. `cpio` can write tar archives and is designed to take the list of files to archive from stdin.

```
find mydir -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | cpio -o -H ustar -0 > mydir.tar
```

Using `find` and `cpio` is a more unix-y approach in that you let `find` do the file selection with all the power that it has, and let `cpio` do the archiving. It is worth learning this simple use of `cpio`, as you find it easy to solve problems you bang your ahead against when trying `tar`.

Comment: Brilliant!  I've used cpio in the distant past, but never knew of the ustar option.

Comment: This worked much better for me than the accepted answer.

Comment: just a nit.  the -maxdepth 1 should come before the -type f or you'll get a warning from some finds

Comment: Thanks @kdubs. I've updated the answer to put `-maxdepth` before `-type`.

Answer (score 4):

You may even use `find ... -print0` and `tar ... --null` directly without using `xargs` at all.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tar cvf mydir.tar --null -T -
```

In the given example, the `--no-recursion` option to `tar` is not necessary because only paths of files (and not directories) will be passed from `find` to `tar`.

Using the `--no-recursion` option to `tar` in the following example, however, prevents `tar` from double archiving directories. `find` will do the directory tree recursion instead of `tar` then.

```
# compare
find . -print0 | tar cf mydir.tar --null -T -
tar -tf mydir.tar | nl

find . -print0 | tar cf mydir.tar --null --no-recursion -T -
tar -tf mydir.tar | nl
```

Answer (score 3):

As the introductory paragraph in `man tar` says (last sentence),

> The use of a directory name always implies that the
>          subdirectories below should be included in the archive.

Which I understand as a "no" answer to your question.

Comment: Good catch, except that tar now includes numerous exclusion meachisms (e.g. `--no-recursion`, `--exclude-tag`, etc.). I am looking into  `--exclude-tag` which looks promising but seems to be the exact opposite of what I am looking for.

Comment: I tried this and I saw characters being removed from long pathnames.  Using tar with -T and --null as camh proposed avoided this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements. If you want to store the regular files in `mydir` but not its subdirectories, the easiest way is to use zsh, where matching regular files only is the simple matter of using the `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
tar cf mydir.tar mydir/*(.)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
star -c -C startdir -find . ! -type d > out.tar
```

Omit `-C startdir` and replace `.` with `startdir` if it should appear in the archive.

This is the most efficient method based on the features of libfind. Libfind also offers primaries `-chown` `-chgrp` `-chmod` that modify struct stat in place and allow to archive different metadata. This also works in list and extract mode and avoids the need to extract the whole archive in many cases.

Comment: Can you use `-find` in `-copy` mode. The man page synopsis suggests you can but I've not been able to make it work (while trying to answer [How to copy modified files while preserving folder structure](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265241)) (with schily-2016-02-10)

Comment: I did not test this for a longer time. It may be that there currently is a bug. The man page says that the last argument would be the extraction directory, but when I try this, I get: "Path arguments not yet supported in extract mode". Is this what you get when you try?

Comment: yes. The man page also says you can only have find arguments after -find but if I put the destination directory before -find I also get an error

Comment: There is code to switch off the find code in the extract process and the error message is from an incorrect check that expects -c but should also permit -copy. In -copy mode, the find parser should not include the last argument.

Comment: Please give me a week, I have a lot to do and fixing the problem takes a few hours because there need to be testing as well.

Comment: There is a new (preliminary) version of the schily tools that include an updated star: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/ a scheduled update will follow and a new star release (star-1.5.4) will be created after a delay.

Comment: A final solution now has been published in the schily tools at sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/schily-2016-03-11.tar.bz2 this also fixes a problem from a missing setlocale() in star and this enables -C directrory for `star -find`.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution.

`find mydir -type f -printf '%P\0'|tar czvf mydir.tar.gz -C mydir --null -T -`

This might be costly a little, but anyway it will work, because this doesn't depend on xargs.

Answer (score -1):

dir=your_dir ; cd $dir ; tar -cvf file.tar `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print`