# How to copy modified files while preserving folder structure

Tags: shell, command-line, files, file-copy, timestamps

I have made many changes to files in my PHP project and I want to push those changes to our server via FileZilla FTP. Rather than push all of the files, I would like to find only the files that have been modified in the last 14 days and copy those to a `/ModifiedFiles` folder, preserving the folder structure. This way I can simply drag the contents of the `/ModifiedFiles` folder into FileZilla and it will overwrite all the necessary files in the appropriate folders.

If I was using Windows, I could run this line of code and it would accomplish what I want:

```
xcopy RUF_Donation_Web ModifiedFiles /S /V /I /R /D:02-09-2016
```

How can I accomplish this in my Bash terminal on my Mac (OS X Yosemite)?

Comment: Can you use `rsync` instead?

Answer (score 5):

That's a typical job for `cpio` or `pax`:

```
find . -type f -mtime -14 -print0 | pax -0 -rw /ModifiedFiles
```

You could also use the `-l` option, to make links instead of copies. It doesn't work properly with the `pax` command on Debian, but maybe the one on OS/X doesn't have the same problem.

You can do something similar with `cpio` (an ancestor of `pax`), but the `cpio` implementation on OS/X doesn't seem to support a `-0`/`--null` option which would allow arbitrary file names. If you know your file names don't contain newline characters, you can still do:

```
find . -type f -mtime -14 | cpio -dp /ModifiedFiles
```

Both Debian (GNU) and OS/X versions of `cpio` also have a `-l` option to make links instead of copies. (and the one of Debian seems to work properly).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement is build in rsync. You can just `rsync -a /source /dest`. You can put that in a simple script and then add it as a cron job. If you want to keep logs of what has been copied you can append `--log-file=[File]` option. You can find more info here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync