# Finding files and copy with folder structure intact

Tags: find, rsync, file-copy, directory-structure

I am searching files who have either been created or modified for the last 60 minuts. I find these via

`find ~/data/ -cmin -60 -mmin -60 -type f`

~ the home directory `/usr/wg/`

After that I want to copy these files and preserve the main folder structure...
The results of the find command are for instance...

```
/usr/wg/data/foo1/file1.txt
/usr/wg/data/foo2/bar2/file2.txt
...
```

Now when I use

```
rsync -a `find ~/data/ -cmin -60 -mmin -60 -type f` ~/vee/
```

In the folder `~/vee/` I get

```
/usr/wg/vee/usr/wg/data/foo1/file1.txt
/usr/wg/vee/usr/wg/data/foo2/bar2/file2.txt
...
```

While I want

```
/usr/wg/vee/foo1/file1.txt
/usr/wg/vee/foo2/bar2/file2.txt
...
```

How do I achieve this? I looked at

1. [How to copy modified files while preserving folder structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265241/how-to-copy-modified-files-while-preserving-folder-structure)
2. https://serverfault.com/questions/180853/how-to-copy-file-preserving-directory-path-in-linux
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/bash-copy-named-files-recursively-preserving-folder-structure

and several other answers, but I do not seem to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your command on this way:

```
cd ~/data; find . -cmin -60 -mmin -60 -type f
```

to be able to get from find relative paths

And maybe something like

```
find ...  -exec cp -r "{}" ../vee/ \;
```

will do the work with copy the files with subdirectory structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--parents` switch:

```
cd ~/data; find . -cmin -60 -mmin -60 -type f -exec cp --parents "{}" ~/vee/
```

From [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):

```
--parents
use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

that is, when you get in the path result:

```
./foo1/file1.txt
./foo2/bar2/file2.txt
```

`cp` will use the full path of the input file and add it to the target path as follows:

```
~/vee/./foo1/file1.txt
~/vee/./foo2/bar2/file2.txt
```

and recreates this directory structure

Comment: `cp(1)` tells me `--parents - use full source file name under DIRECTORY`. Please explain what is the change in behavior of the `cp` command in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @Rich I also needed such a solution (copying the whole path), and this switch helped me. That is why I gave this my answer.

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you could add a bit of an explanation of what exactly `--parents` does (and how that depends on the exact form of the source path, if at all), instead of an one-liner like this.