# How to tar all file contents only, into a flat archive?

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, tar

I want to tar compress every file in the directory, including the files in sub directories into a tar archive without any sub directories. So, that all the files are together in a single archive directory.

Comment: Have you tried these https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24870/tar-files-only-no-directories ?

Comment: Yes, but that question is asking for just the files in the base directory. I want to recursively get every file in the directory including the files in its sub directories.

Comment: With GNU tar, you could use `--transform` to strip the paths - however the resulting archive would still include the (then empty) directories I think

Comment: Yeah. It seems like I'll have to $ find the files and put them into a temp directory then just tar that directory instead.

Comment: @PhilipMiller with the `find` options, you could just remove the `-maxdepth 1` to enable recursion.

Comment: `find <src> -type f -name '*.<file-extension>' -exec cp -at <des> {} +`

Comment: The command `star -c -f /tmp/out.tar -s^*/^^ somedir` does what you like. If you like to avoid empty directories to appear in the archive, use: `star -c -f /tmp/out.tar -s^*/^^ -find somedir ! -type d`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solution , without copy using tar in append mode

```
find /etc -type f | ( 
   CNT=1 ; 
   TARDST="/tmp/a_flat_archive.tar" 
   while read F ; 
   do 
       D=$(dirname $F) ; 
       SF=$(basename $F) ; 
       if [ $CNT -eq 1 ]; 
       then 
           tar -C "$D" -cf $TARDST  "$SF" ;
       else 
           tar -C "$D" --append -f $TARDST "$SF" ;
       fi ; 
       CNT=$(( $CNT +1 )) ;
   done 
)
```

Comment: Note that `--append` is a GNU extension to `tar`.  If you're stuck with [POSIX `tar`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) (the question currently is not tagged specifically enough to tell), the `-u` update option can be used to update an existing tar file.

Comment: Both, the append option and -u are dangerous with GNU tar in case that the archive is not created with the same tar implementation or same command. GNU tar does not honor existing archive formats and happily creates archives that change the archive format in the middle. Such archives tend to be unreadable by other cleanly written archivers.

Comment: BTW: did you read my example that creates the archive in one pass using `star`?